# Can't create a method to make visible a words letters randomly

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method to make some of the word's letters visible and other ones *. This is actually a simple word guessing game. I ask the user to choose whether they want to give an answer or request a letter. For example if the answer is "ball" and user decides to request a word, ball should turn into "*a**".

That is the method I have came up with:

```
public static void showALetter(String correctAnswer) {
    int randomLetterIndex = (int) Math.random() % (correctAnswer.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswer.length(); i++) {
        if (i == randomLetterIndex) {
            System.out.print(correctAnswer.charAt(randomLetterIndex));
        } else {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

It only shows the first letter of the correct answer at every single request. What should I do ?

Comment: `int randomLetterIndex = (int) (Math.random() * correctAnswer.length());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a `double` with a value between zero and one (technically `[0.0, 1.0)` written as a mathematical interval). This is not what you want, so you instead need to use the newer `java.util.Random` class:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomLetterIndex = random.nextInt(correctAnswer.length());
```

The `random.nextInt(int limit)` method will return a value from zero (inclusive) to `limit` (exclusive) which is what you need here for your puproses.

If you're going to use random numbers over and over again, then create your `Random` instance as a static class member and have your methods refer to that, so that you only create the object once.

Answer (score 3):

Math.random() returns a number from zero to one. So, your randomLetterIndex will always be zero. Use this instead.

```
(int) (Math.random() * correctAnswer.length())
```

This will give a random number between 0 and correctAnswer.length() - 1.

Comment: There is no need to use `Math.floor()`

Comment: Yups. int returns the floor value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a double higher or equal than 0 and less then 1, `(int) Math.random()` will always return 0.

Use

```
(int)(Math.random() * correctAnswer.length())
```

The modulo is useless here, this way you always hit inside the given string as `(int)` cast returns the floor value so the result will never be equal or higher than `correctAnswer.length()`.